# Trying to acces MySql database from android app

Tags: android, mysql, database, xamarin

I created an app which can send and get data from my database. The problem is when i install and try to acces the database from another phone, i get error starting with

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could not resolve host 'sql11.freesqldatabase.com'
     at System.Net.Dns.Error_11001 (System.String hostName)[0x00015] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0
     at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName
     ...
```

(It continues, but i cant copy the whole error.)

What could be the problem? It worked on Android 6.0, the second phone has 5.0, both have acces to internet.

Comment: it's a DNS error.  It's can't find the hostname.

Comment: it works on my phone but it doesnt on another, thats the problem

Comment: are both phone connecting on the same network?  Do they both have the same network config?  Have you tried using an IP instead of hostname?  Have you used any networking tools to debug connectivity issues to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string, may be it is wrong.

Make sure your user has all access privileges for the database, because many providers only give access from localhost. You can enable the remote access by requesting them.

Comment: string is ok, i cant figure out why it works on one phone only

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to a remote database is not a good idea. Perhaps it's easier at first, but then there will be problems. I advise you to use REST API.Please read this [article](https://xamarinhelp.com/connecting-remote-database-xamarin-forms/).